# Back Button Not visible in Child View Controller

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I am working on a iOS App with Swift3 and xCode8. I am in middle of a situation in which i have to open a same ViewController (Help) from multiple view controllers. To Achieve this i embedded Navigation controller to each view controller from where i want to open the "Help" View Controller and than control drag the segue (show) to "Help" View Controller from each of them. But the Back button is visible only in one case and in all the other cases there is no way to go back to root view controller.

Forgot My Password --> Help (Back Button Visible)

Login --> Help  (Back Button not visible)

Register --> Help (Back Button not visible)

Landing --> Help (Back Button not visible)

Dashboard --> Help (Back Button not visible)

One more noticeable thing is that in the case (i.e. Forgot my password) it is working fine, the navigation bar shifted/adjusted the UI and made space for itself but in all the other cases it covers my UI in root view controller. Although, this overlapping doesn't effect the UI at runtime and it is visually normal as it should be. I don't know weather it is a useful information or not as i am new to iOS development, I just want to clarify the situation.

For Your Information:

I am Testing the app on a real device (iPhone 5C).

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

**Update**

Storyboard Screenshots

Forgot My Password (Where everything is working fine)

[image]

Landing (One of the screen where issue is)

[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your storyboard file?

Comment: Yes Sure! Give me a moment let me update my question.

Comment: did you try push by programming ?

Comment: no,  as i thot it  is working in one view controller it should work with other also.

Answer (score 2):

If you try to push a UINavigationController in another UINavigationController it does not do push, it does present that is why you are not able to see a back button because back button only appears in push. So what you should do is push all the UIViewControllers in a single UINavigationController or use UITabBarController if you want multiple UINavigationController and this should solve your problem.

Comment: Do you mean from all the root ViewControllers i control+drag segue push to a UINavigationController and then from that UINavigationController ontrol+drag segue (push) to "Help" View Controller. Am i Right ?

Comment: No i mean plan the architecture of your app so that it has only one UINavigationController. If you want multiple UINavigationControllers then use UITabBarController

Comment: No, it doesn't solved my actual problem. But surely it is good piece of advice. 1+ for advice. :)